# Basic sequence question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. If $x_n\geq 0$ $\forall$ $n\in \mathbb{N}$, show that $\displaystyle x=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n \geq 0$.

---

I know that this is quite an easy problem but I am really bad at writing proofs for such obvious statements. How do I start the proof in this case?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume that $x < 0$. In order for the sequence to converge, we must be able to find an $N$ such that $|x_n - x| < |x|$ whenever $n \geq N$. This implies that $|x_N - x|  < |x|$ and so $x_N < 0$. But this is a contradiction with the assumption that $x_n \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, $x \geq 0$.

Comment: This might be a dumb question but why are you talking about the convergence?

Comment: @PranavArora since you are writing $\displaystyle x=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n$. In other words, you assume that $\{ x_n \}$ converges to $x$. Thus, is follows that, whenever $n \geq N$, $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$. In the above answer, I've set $\epsilon = |x|$.

Comment: Hmm...but why do you set $\epsilon =|x|$?

Comment: @PranavArora Because I can (by the definition of convergence of sequences).

Answer (score 1):

If $x<0$ then $|x_n -x| =x_n -x \geq -x $ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? I do not see how this is a solution to the given problem. Thanks!